# Weighted Average - omit data if missing from value or weight

Tags: pandas, missing-data, weighted-average

I have code like this

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'value':[10,20,np.nan,40],
...                         'weight':[1,np.nan,3,4]}) 
>>> df1
   value  weight
0   10.0     1.0
1   20.0     NaN
2    NaN     3.0
3   40.0     4.0
>>> (df1["value"] * df1["weight"]).sum() / df1["weight"].sum()
21.25
```

I want to omit data from calculation  if values or weight is missing . i.e I want weighted average like like
(10*1 + 40*4) /(1+4) = 34

Please help if this is possible using single expression in pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  filter first with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), mask is created by [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.notnull.html) and [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for check all `True` values per row:

```
df1 = df1[df1.notnull().all(axis=1)]
print (df1)
   value  weight
0   10.0     1.0
3   40.0     4.0

df2 = (df1["value"] * df1["weight"]).sum() / df1["weight"].sum()
print (df2)
34.0
```

Or check both columns separately:

```
df1 = df1[df1["value"].notnull() & df1["weight"].notnull()]
print (df1)
   value  weight
0   10.0     1.0
3   40.0     4.0
```

Simplier solution with [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df1 = df1.dropna()
print (df1)
   value  weight
0   10.0     1.0
3   40.0     4.0
```

Or if is necessary specify columns:

```
df1 = df1.dropna(subset=['value','weight'])
print (df1)
   value  weight
0   10.0     1.0
3   40.0     4.0
```